# Want this regex work for min 8 characters. No Max Limit

Tags: javascript, regex

My Regex: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])`

It accepts at least 1 lowercase letter, 1 uppercase letter, 1 number and 1 special character.

I want this to work for minimum 8 characters. Should not match if string length less than 8.

I have tried `(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])){8,}` this. But it still accepts lengths less than 8 `Abc@123`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appended the limiting quantifier to a capture group 1 (around the whole pattern) meaning you want to repeat the lookahead checks 8 or more times.

Either add one more lookahead:

```
/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])/
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI5fS1/1).

Alternatively, you may add `.{8,}` at the end

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&]).{8,}/
                                               ^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN0hR2/1).

And no need to repeat the `$` character inside the character class (`[$@$!%*?&]` -> `[@$!%*?&]`), unless you meant something else.

The lookahead at the start variation may turn out preferable in cases when the string won't match due to its length.

```js
console.log(/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])/.test("1sD$"))
console.log(/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])/.test("1sD$2sD$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet and 1 Number:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$"
```

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$"
```

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
```

Comment: These string patterns won't work correctly inside `RegExp` constructor.